# e.preventdefault() based on nested divs and lis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of divs nested into each other and I want to prevent default on links only if a ul has list items. See the example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".layer-1").click(function(e) {
   if (($(e.target).is(".link")) && ($(this, ".list").children().length == 0)) {
        console.log("following link!");
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer-1">
  <div class="layer-2">
    <a href="jsfiddle.net" class="link">Don't follow</a>
    <div class="layer-3">
      <div class="layer-4">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="layer-1">
  <div class="layer-2">
    <a href="jsfiddle.net" class="link">follow!</a>
    <div class="layer-3">
      <div class="layer-4">
        <ul class="list">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The basic premise is that I'm checking if the target of the click event is the link and utilizing `this` to target the UL and check for the amount of list items. If it's zero follow the link otherwise `e.preventDefault()`. What seems to be happening is that they're all preventDefault() despite the amount of list items.

As a troubleshoot I console logged `$(this, ".list").children().length` but it's always one. Why? How do I target `.list` in this markup structure instance?

I even went as far as:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".layer-1").click(function(e) {
  console.log($(this, ".layer-1 > .layer-2 > .layer-3 > .layer-4 > .list").children().length)
   if (($(e.target).is(".link")) && ($(this, ".layer-1 > .layer-2 > .layer-3 > .layer-4 > .list").children().length == 0)) {
        console.log("following link!");
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer-1">
  <div class="layer-2">
    <a href="jsfiddle.net" class="link">Don't follow</a>
    <div class="layer-3">
      <div class="layer-4">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="layer-1">
  <div class="layer-2">
    <a href="jsfiddle.net" class="link">follow!</a>
    <div class="layer-3">
      <div class="layer-4">
        <ul class="list">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And using the `>` in my CSS selection but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target `.list`. ;)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".layer-1").click(function(e) {
  
  console.log($(this).find(".list").children().length)
  
   if (($(e.target).is(".link")) && ($(this).find(".list").children().length == 0)) {
        console.log("following link!");
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Event prevented.");
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer-1">
  <div class="layer-2">
    <a href="jsfiddle.net" class="link">Don't follow</a>
    <div class="layer-3">
      <div class="layer-4">
        <ul class="list">
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="layer-1">
  <div class="layer-2">
    <a href="jsfiddle.net" class="link">follow!</a>
    <div class="layer-3">
      <div class="layer-4">
        <ul class="list">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Duh! totally forgot about `find()`!

Answer (score 1):

You have the arguments backwards in `$(this, ".list")`. It should be `$(".list", this)`. The first argument is what you're searching for, the second optional argument is the container to search in (instead of the document by default).

This is equivalent to `$(this).find(".list")`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of a second argument... ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find(".list")`
should do the trick

You just had the params in the wrong order for $(this, ".list")